# Deleting a row inside a table - AngularJS and FireBase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

The problem I am encountering is that the function does not work when I try to delete a row. What I am trying to achieve is to delete a row inside the table by clicking on the red button.

[Link to my plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/z7iTCKIRwvTDGEIUf6av?p=preview)

This is what I have added in index.html

```
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
    </button>
```

This is what I have added in script.js

```
  $scope.removeRow = function removeRow(item) {
    var index = $scope.myData.indexOf(item);
    if (index !== -1) {
        $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong object .

```
ng-click="removeRow(row)"
```

If you wanna remove data from `customers` you have to pass `customer`.

In js you are trying to remove data from `$scope.myData` instead of `$scope.customers` . $scope.myData is an object and object don't have the method name **[`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

Try like this

JS

```
  $scope.removeRow = function removeRow(item) {
    var index = $scope.customers.map(function(x){return x.CustomerPlateNumber;}).indexOf(item.CustomerPlateNumber);
    if (index !== -1) {
        $scope.customers.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(customer)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/fy5yojXJwpRDk20THL6y?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This works in front-end, however the row is not deleted from the database. If you try to delete a row, then update the code. The row comes back.. Is there a way of deleting the row also from the database? Link to plunker after I added your modification: https://plnkr.co/edit/z7iTCKIRwvTDGEIUf6av?p=preview

Comment: well this code isn't for database delete .. this is for client side only .. to delete from database you have to write code in your server side and pass data from client @DlerAri

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.